# Get subnets and NICs associated with a given NSG for all subscriptions

Tags: powershell, azure-nsg

I am new to PS.... trying to get NSGs in a given subscription (and once this works to do this for all subscriptions) to show the following properties (NSG Name, Location, Resource Group, Subnet, NIC).

I am using the below script from [Getting list of NSG and corresponding Subnet or NIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685818/getting-list-of-nsg-and-corresponding-subnet-or-nic) but it lists same information for each NSG multiple times equal to the number of NSGs in the subscription so it has to be something wrong in the script

```
$azNsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
       
 foreach ( $azNsg in $azNsgs ) {

 if ($azNsg.Subnets.Id -ne $null) {

     $NsgSubnets = $azNsg.Subnets.Id.Split('/')[-1]

}
         Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup | `
            Select-Object `
            @{name = 'NSG Name'; expression = {$azNsg.Name} },  `
            @{name = 'Location'; expression = {$azNsg.Location} }, `
            @{name = 'Resource Group Name'; expression = {$azNsg.ResourceGroupName} },  `
            @{name = 'Subnets'; expression = $NsgSubnets } 
       
}
```

Also would like the script to ignore null values for NIC/Subnet as some NSGs would be assigned to Subnets whilst others to NICs Finally an NSG could be assigned to multiple subnets/NICs so how do I get the $azNsg.Subnets.Id.Split('/')[-1] part working for multiple entries in Subnets.Id or NetworkInterfaces.Id and not just the last one ?

Thanks

Comment: You do not need to call `Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup` the second time inside of your `foreach` loop. Just use `$azNsg | Select-Object ....`.

Comment: Many thanks @AdminOfThings.. that seems to have solved that part.. could you help me please with the second part of the query where I want to see subnets and/or NICs associated with each NSG and it should list all subnets/nics not just the last one

Comment: Index `[-1]` gets the last element of an array. If you don't want only the last element, then you should remove that index. Since you are using an `if` statement to set `$NsgSubnets`, it is not reset for when there are no subnets. The first line of your `foreach` needs to be something like `$NsgSubnets = $null`.

Comment: After looking at the linked post, I think I understand more of the issue. The subnet ID is a path and you only want the leaf of that path (the name only). You could try `$NsgSubnets = $azNsg.Subnets.foreach({$_.Id.Split('/')[-1]})`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$azNsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
       
    foreach ( $azNsg in $azNsgs ) {

        $NsgSubnets = $null

        if (!$azNsg.Subnets.Id) {
            $NsgSubnets = $azNsg.Subnets.foreach({$_.Id.Split('/')[-1]})
        }

         $azNsg |
            Select-Object @{name = 'NSG Name'; expression = {$_.Name}},
                @{name = 'Location'; expression = {$_.Location}},
                @{name = 'Resource Group Name'; expression = {$_.ResourceGroupName}},  
                @{name = 'Subnets'; expression = {$NsgSubnets -join ','}}
       
    }
```

Overall improvements include:

- You only need to run `Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup` once since you are storing its output into a variable. You can simply retrieve its contents from the variable. This makes the code execute faster.
- Since your objects could have multiple subnets, you need to handle the case when `$azNsg.Subnets` is an array of non-null objects. Using the `foreach()` method, you can process code against each element of that array. When PowerShell fully enumerates array output (as it does in the case without `foreach()`), your multiple subnet arrays become one large array on the final output. Then `[-1]` only returns the very last `Id` value.
- Setting `$NsgSubnets` inside of an `if` statement without an `else` statement leads to bad data later in the code execution. If the network has a subnet, `$NsgSubnets` will be set and returned properly. However, if the next network has no subnet, you are not updating the value of `$NsgSubnets`. Therefore, it will output the previous network's subnet information in your `Select-Object` command.
- You don't always need backticks for continuation. `|` and `,` separating elements automatically supports continuation. See [Natural Line Continuations](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html).

Comment: I tried that but it does not return any subnets even when some of the NSGs (not all) have subnets associated

Comment: Maybe the subnets need to be joined as a single string. I added code to do that. If that doesn't work, please show a sample output of `$aznsg.subnets`. I don't have a way of verifying this.

Comment: I could not get anything from $aznsg.subnets however I ran the below to query the NSG that is assigned to multiple subnets

`Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name <NSG-01>

 {
                           "Id": "/subscriptions/0000000.....VNET-01/subnets/SUB-NONPROD-01",
                           "IpAllocations": []
                         },
                         {
                           "Id": "/subscriptions/000000000..../VNET-01/subnets/SUB-PROD-01",
                           "IpAllocations": []
`

Comment: ...based on the above I would expect SUB-NONPROD-01 and SUB-PROD-01 to be shown in the subnet column

Comment: I have got the data by using 

`@{name = 'Subnets'; expression = { $NsgSubnets | ForEach ({$_.id.split('/')[-1] }) } }`

The output is on separate lines

subnet1
subnet2
subnet3
subnet4

However when trying to export the above subnets into a singe cell using export-excel, I get System.Object[]. Surprisingly this works fine if I use export-csv so I am assuming its excel that's the culprit here ?

`Export-Excel -Path "$($home)\Documents\Work\Powershell\NSG-Summary-v12.xlsx" -WorksheetName ($azsub.Name) -Append -AutoSize -FreezeTopRow -BoldTopRow -AutoFilter`

Any ideas ?